# Limits question. $\lim_{x\to0}\space \frac {\sin(\pi (\cos ^2 (x)))}{x^2}$

Tags: limits

Please solve this limit question without using L'Hopital's Law...
$$\lim_{x\to0}\space \frac {\sin(\pi (\cos ^2 (x)))}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *equivalents*, more precisely, $\sin u\sim_0 u$.

Note first that $\;\sin(\pi\cos^2x)=\sin(\pi-\pi\sin^2x)=\sin(\pi\sin^2x)$, hence
$$\frac{\sin(\pi\cos^2x)}{x^2}=\frac{\sin(\pi\sin^2x)}{x^2}\sim_0\frac{\pi\sin^2x}{x^2}\sim_0\frac{\pi \,x^2}{x^2}=\pi.$$

Comment: I really cannot understand what has happened above... Please elaborate!

Comment: Actually, I got it.!!! Thanx!!!

Comment: You're welcome. It ws intended to be a sketch rather than a detailed solution. More educational in my opinion.